# DC Motor Question

Tags: electrical

I am not an engineer, just looking for a bit of advice. I hope that it is ok that I ask this here.

I have a DC Motor from a treadmill. It is a DC 2.25hp, 180v, 4700 RPM, 7.5 amp motor.

I want to use it to power my small EMCO Lathe. I have an AC (in) to DC (out) variable speed controller. But the speed controller is outputting roughly 210 volts according to my multimeter.

Could this damage the motor if I connected it to the DC out of the variable speed controller seeing the motor says 180 volts? If so how do I go about finding a solution to this issue? Any information or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Damian

Answer (score 1):

It probably will not, because the percentage difference between 180 and 210 is small compared to 210. But the way to tell for sure is to monitor the temperature of the motor case. Every motor has a maximum allowed service temperature, and as long as you stay below that, the motor will be OK. If you can find the manufacturer's name on the case, write them and ask for the max. T on that motor.

Answer (score 1):

it's reasonable to expect that the motor controller uses pulse wave modulation, which sends electricity in brief, carefully timed pulses corresponding to the desired speed or a close approximation thereof. The full voltage provides the best torque and power (redundant?) while not running the motor at full speed. At short duration pulses, there would be no complications.